# ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonWrongUser on Cordova Facebook Connect plugin

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I have an issue with Cordova Facebook plugin when I try to log with FB Connect.

My code :

```
$cordovaFacebook.login(['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_location', 'user_friends'])
    .then(function(success) {
        // some code if success
    }, function (error) {
        // some code if error
    });
```

And I get this error :

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. com.facebook.sdk:ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonWrongUser
```

It works with some users, I don't understant why I get this error. The user has accepted the FB permissions like everyone else.

Comment: Please have a look for your facebook integration in your hybrid app by [nicraboy](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/02/make-facebook-mobile-app-ionic-framework/) if problem persist i will upload a demo project in github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution :

As explained here : https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/479
I need to force logout before trying to re-authenticate.

So, I've just added this :

```
$cordovaFacebook.logout()
    .then(function(success) {
        // my login code 
    });
```

And it works :)